# A way to use unity.configuration in azure functions V2 - .net core

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, unity-container

I have requirement to resolve dependencies from xml file and have used unity dependency injection.
Everythins is working fine in console and ASP.net core applications.

However in .net core functions below piece of code is returning null.

```
var unitySection = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
```

[image: Solution]

I have added app.config and unity.config and marked the properties to be copied to bin on build.

Default output type Function app is Class library, changed to console as well but no luck. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you also add your `unity.config` file ?

Comment: Please notice that, from azure function v2, azure function is no longer based on ConfigurationManager and its APIs, have a look of this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/328#issuecomment-355697529

Answer (score 0):

From v2, azure function doesn't support ConfigurationManager and you can refer to environment variables, you need to use `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`.

Please have a look of this reply of azure teams:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/328#issuecomment-355697529

`ConfigurationManager` is only be used in azure function v1. From v2, it has been moved to a new configuration model:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-3.1

And not based on ConfigurationManager or its APIs any more.:)